# Android, libgdx, Sounds issue

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to play sounds in my game with gdx lib.

See below my code :

```
Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal(Assets.SOUND_DIR_PATH + "test.wav"));
sound.play(0.75f);
```

It works fine while i am debugging with a brekpoint on the line sound.play() but it doesn't work when i am not debugging...

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try putting just the file name, like this

```
Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("test.wav"));
sound.play(0.75f);
```

Works fine for me that way.